# sort columns with different type in data grid view

Tags: sorting, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I have a data grid view with columns : IdentityNumber , Name , Date .
Each column represents different types of values .
identityNumner is an integer , Name is a string , and date is DateTime.

My goal is to click on a column's header and the sort will be done accoding to the types above.
The auto sort without doing anything is sort by string as I can see . 
but how do I achive my goal ?

I have found a solution for my problem . 
Please check the answer below .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution for my problem :

Inside the ctor of the form I registered the data grid view's SortCompare event :

```
    DataGridView1.SortCompare += new DataGridViewSortCompareEventHandler(MyCustomSortFunction);
```

The custom function Iv'e build is :

```
void MyCustomSortFunction(object sender, DataGridViewSortCompareEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // checks if the column's header that was pressed is the identity number - 
            // If so , sort as integer .

            if (e.Column.Name == "colIdentity") 
            {
                int a = Convert.ToInt32(e.CellValue1.ToString());
                int b = Convert.ToInt32(e.CellValue2.ToString());
                e.SortResult = a.CompareTo(b);
                e.Handled = true;
            }
            // checks if the column's header that was pressed is the date - 
            // If so , sort as DateTime .

            else if (e.Column.Name == "colHDate")
            {
                DateTime c = Convert.ToDateTime(e.CellValue1.ToString());
                DateTime d = Convert.ToDateTime(e.CellValue2.ToString());
                e.SortResult = c.CompareTo(d);
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
        catch
        { }
    }
```

Hope my answer will help someone :-)
Shuki .